# Dragging and drop HTML5 function without Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm creating a custom e-mail template. We have a concept that we have a little game inside the e-mail and I know we cannot do crazy things using Javascript etc so I thought I might be able to use the drag and drop version from HTML5. But as you might have guessed I need Javascript to make this function and as you know we cannot use Javascript inside e-mail as it just gets ignored.

So my question is: is there a way to use dragging and dropping (or simulate it?) using pure HTML and maybe a bit CSS?

Comment: No. This is not possible. Until someone proves me wrong...

Comment: hope someone will prove you wrong :X

Comment: yes. let's hope